# How to exculde some fields from REST api response?

Tags: java

I am getting the response from API as

```
Response response=Response.ok(map,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
return response
```

But I want some of the fields to be excluded while returning the response.

The map is of following format:

```
Map<String,OuterClass> map;

class OuterClass{
   int a;
   int b;
   Map<String,InnerClass> map2;
}

Class InnerClass{
   int c;
   int d;

}
```

The json response for example should not include the field 'd' from InnerClass.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: exclude from map??

Comment: @NilankaManoj I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Set` for exclude properties and use `removeIf`,

```
Set<String> excludeProperties=null;
map.entrySet()
        .removeIf(e->excludeProperties.contains(e.getKey()));
return Response.ok(map,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can JsonIgnore property:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


Class InnerClass{
   int c;
   @JsonIgnore
   int d;

}
```

ref : https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/package-summary.html

Comment: But that field is required by other API calls. So do not want to make a change in class.

Comment: So you have to write a custom serializer